# Default type parameter error in template code

Tags: c++, templates

```
1)template <class T = int, class U = double> //compiles

2)template <class T, class U =double> //compiles

3)template <class T = int, class U> //fails
```

Why does 1 and 2 compile whereas 3 does not?

Answer (score 8):

For the same reason why:

```
void f(int = 0, int);
```

fails.

There is no way to use 3rd version default parameter:

```
template<class T = int, class U> class B { ... };

B<, short> var; // ??? no such syntax
```

Answer (score 6):

`(3)` is ill-formed because

C++03 [`Section 14.1/11`] says

> If a template-parameter has a default template-argument, **all subsequent template-parameters shall have a default template-argument supplied**.

Comment: Great answer +1. Where can I get a copy of the standard?

Comment: @JoshD : You can find it [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/) (ISO/IEC 14882 2003 is C++03)

Comment: @JoshD: AFAIK you can't get it for free. However you can look at the drafts of the next standard.

Comment: Although, I would have liked (3) to be valid in case of function templates. We still have TAD (template argument deduction) to determine the trailing, non-defaulted template parameters.

Comment: @sellibitze in that case you can add a default `class = void` and it'll solve your problem.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Interesting. But I don't think it'll work for argument packs.

Answer (score 4):

If you put that into some context, the third way may actually be legal, provided that the second default has been given earlier.

```
template <class T, class U = double>
struct X;

template <class T = int, class U> //here
struct X {};

int main()
{
    X<> x;
    X<float> y;
    X<char, char> z;
}
```